# Removing junction points from binary image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have thinned the segmented image and found junction points marked as green points in an image (right image) then I delete junction pixels from image to disconnect each vessel segment but 2 more pixels, marked as arrow in right figure, which are not the junction pixels is removed. I wrote following code:

```
  test3 = bwmorph(BinaryImage,'thin',Inf);
  [rj3, cj3, re3, ce3] = findendsjunctions(test3, 1);
  temp_withoutjun=test3;
  temp_withoutjun(rj3, cj3)=0;
  figure, imshow(temp_withoutjun)
  hold on
  plot(cj3, rj3,'*g')
```

I dont understand why 2 extra pixel is removed.  findendsjunctions.m and dependent file show.m can  downloaded from here: http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/LineSegments/findendsjunctions.m   and here  http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Misc/show.m  respectively

That will be great if some suggest some solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't spent very long reading it, but your method to find junctions and end points by counting crossings seems flawed. Would be easier to just count the white neighbours of a while pixel. If the count is greater than 3, it's a junction. If the count is 1, it's an end point.